# Convert Waveform Image to Audio

Tags: c#, audio, playback, waveform

I have a wave form image:[image: Waveform Image] created using http://convert.ing-now.com/ although the creation I'd hope would be irrelevant!

I'd like to take the waveform image and play back the sound. Ideally using c# but I'm happy to just get it working in any language.

Have done extensive Google research, but found nothing that fits the bill.

Comment: Well, I'm not an audio expert but I would say that you need the amplitude and the frequency of the wave, which from the image I can't see.

Comment: This is jut a tiny number of volume samples most likely highy compressed. No way to recreate the sound it came from.

Comment: If I created it in the first place and knew all the data. Would it be possible to recreate the audio?

Comment: Note that the term 'convert' is used a little as in 'convert people to jpg'.. Yes you can re-create the sound, but only if you had the volume at each sample. even at low-fi samples rates of, say 5kHz that would still be way as bif image of 5000+256 pixels per second. But yes you could read the pixels, find the volumes and build up a wave. But why on earth would one do that?? If ou have the data, storing it in an image is a terrible idea..

Comment: Basically I've been asked by a colleague if it's possible to create an app to read wave forms like this and play back the original audio. She's been using the Convert.ing-now.com website to go the other way. Was wondering if we can go back to original audio..

Comment: I see. So the answer has to be: I principle yes but in practice no. To understand better I recommend looking at sound sample image fully zoomed in

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll report back.

Comment: @TaW I would like to do so in order to hear my future baby's heartbeat from visual waveform printed on the ultrasound exam report. That's one use case for this question at least.